JBoss EAP 7 not finding a package in lib folder
I currently have my Apache httpclient jar file inside the lib folder within my .ear file. This file is inside the standalone/deployments folder of my JBoss EAP 7 directory. When I run the application, it will yield a NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/httpclient/HttpMethod
I have verified that this file exists, in the right package, and is inside the .jar file inside the lib folder.
I am aware that ear/lib jar files are visible to all modules within the .ear file, so I am unsure why it cannot detect this. I have the isolated ear deployment tag unset, which defaults to false. I also have set Class-Path variables to the file, which is ignored because it says it is already visible.
I have also tried to turn it into a module, with no change.

Is your EAR exploded or an archive?
